# What kind of rotation unit is used by this game?

Tags: math, rotation, physics, radians

I am observing a rotation value of a character in a game, and its value confuses me.

I am wondering, what kind of unit is used here? It does not seem to be radian or degrees.

When the character faces...
north, rotation = 0.014887573
north-east, rotation = -0.28192267
east, rotation = -0.7139419
south-east, rotation = -0.9176189
south, rotation = -0.99983466
west, rotation = 0.6936041
south-west, rotation = 0.90622354
north-west, rotation = 0.36119097

There appears to be somekind of exponential increase when facing a more southern rotation. Does this scale make sense to anyone?

**Update**: there appears to be another variable which somehow seems to resolve the actual rotation when multiplied with the above value when facing east or north. If mulitplied, when facing west the value will be 0.5 and when facing east it will be -0.5.

However, this multiplier becomes 0 when facing south and 1 when facing north, so when you multiple that with the first value they both become 0.

What kind of rotation representation uses multiple values in a 3D scene?

Comment: If you start south then move round the east, north, west then back to south it goes from -1 to 1

Comment: True, but the scale inbetween does not seem to make much sense. Or does it? The increments are not linear.

Comment: If the character is moving in a 3D world, then the camera position might cause this non-uniformity.

Comment: @Itamar, that would make sense. So probably I am looking at the wrong values. I shall investigate, thanks!

Comment: @Itamar, after testing it appears that the camera has no effect on the value at all. It only appears to be actual rotation of the character.

Comment: I updated the original question as I found another value which is related.

Comment: Added my own answer, arc sine seems to do something senseful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating the arc sine of the above values it seems to make more sense.

North will become 0
South will become 90

West will become 45
East will become -45

I question though, why is the scale from 0 to 90 (north to south) and not from 0 to 180?